# Weird screen scaling and sprite displaying

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

When i scaled my window, the sprites were a lot smaller, also, sprites do not display after reaching about halfway across the screen. The background color blue still displays but the sprites get cut off.

[image]

In the above image as you can see the sprites did not stretch with the screen, and the sprites near the top are being sliced when they reach that part of the screen.

Comment: Did the sprites appear smaller, or did it keep the same size? Sprites in XNA usually don't scale with the window, unless it's programmed to do so.

Comment: @Steven yeah they did. I also added an image of the problem i'm having if it helps.

Comment: @Steven i just fixed it by putting graphicsDevice.ApplyChanges() in Update. But now all my sprites except for a small few are displaying as black boxes, any idea why?